# Proving the limit using $\epsilon -N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Basically I'm trying to prove that the below limit is 0

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{3+2n}{5n^2+2}}$$

Would it make sense to set $$ M =\frac{4}{5\epsilon}$$
as from $$\left|\frac{(3+2n)}{(5n^2+2)}\right| < \epsilon$$
you get $$\frac{(3+2n)}{(5n^2+2)} < \frac{(4n)}{(5n^2+2)} < \frac{(4n)}{(5n^2)}<\epsilon.$$

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use that$$\frac{3+2n}{5n^2+2}<\frac{1}{n}$$